# String Concatnation on a master table column with out duplicates

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

Can any one please help me by providing sql to concat the string column with out duplicates using only SQL which should work on all the dbs. I need the query for record view / psquery in peoplesoft.

EG: I have master table CheckList (common_id +seq_3c is key )as

```
COMMON_ID SEQ_3C CHECKLIST_CD   
AA0012   2      C     
AA0012   1  GRAPP   
AA0014   1  GD  
AA0014   2  SD
```

and child table checklist item as

```
COMMON_ID SEQ_3C CHECKLIST_SEQ CHKLST_ITEM_CD STATUS_DT  
    AA0012    2       100          ESSAY 12-MAY-13   
    AA0012    2       200          TOEFL 12-MAY-13   
    AA0012    2       300          TRANS 13-MAY-13   
    AA0012    1       100          APFEE 10-MAY-13  
    AA0012    1       200          GRE 12-MAY-13   
    AA0012    1       300          TRANS 12-MAY-13   
    AA0012    1       400          RECLTR 26-JAN-00   
    AA0014    1       100          APFEE 10-MAY-13   
    AA0014    1       200          GRE 12-MAY-13   
    AA0014    2       100          APFEE 12-MAY-13   
    AA0014    2       200          GRE 26-JAN-00
```

I have condition on child table's column status date(eg: 12_May-13 dated rows ) so for those rows i want to get the single show for each common id with concatted values of checklist_cd with out duplicates.

like as

```
COMMON_ID CHECKLIST_CD
AA0012 C,GRAPP
AA0014 GD, SD
```

please suggest / provide sql for record view/psquery in peoplesoft which should be validated on all the dbs in this case. I need only in sql(pl/sql shouldnt be used).
If It can be done with any no of intermediate sql/ temporary tables thats also fine.

Thanks,
Shyam

Comment: You are looking for aggregation string concatenation.  There is no standard way to do this across databases.  If you provide the databases you are actually using, then someone can help you.

Comment: in peoplesoft we need to give generic query. If any one can help it will be helpfull. It can be done with any no of intermediate sql/ temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question, do you want dynamic columns?
If so, you can do that on the XMLP report or cross table in crystal...
Using peopletools, you will have to write a HTML area

Answer (score 0):

You will have to achieve this by using peoplecode logic. This cannot be achieved through a static SQL.